# How to bind an item command in user conrol to viewmodel command?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I have an UserControl. In my UserControl i have a button that I want bind its command to my ViewModel command. Can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it...I can define a DependensyProperty typof RelayCommand in my usercontrol and bind my DependensyProperty  to my ViewModel Command

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could add a [routed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) to your user control which gets invoked when the button is pressed.

You can then use various techniques to invoke the view model verb when the user control event fires.

E.g. you could use an [attached property](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/attachedcommandbehavior-aka-acb/), or I would recommend using an MVVM framework such as [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) which has [Actions](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions&referringTitle=Documentation) that makes it even more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you mean but I take a shot.

In your code behind, define a [RoutedCommand](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/03/18/understanding-routed-commands/):

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static RoutedCommand Click =
        new RoutedCommand("Click", typeof(UserControl));
}
```

Then it the xaml, set up a command binding:

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding 
        Command="{x:Static MyNameSpace:MyUserControl.Click}"
        CanExecute="ClickCanExecute"
        Executed="ClickExecuted"/>
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

Then add the handlers in the code behind:

```
private void ClickCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true;
}

private void ClickExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO execution logic goes here
}
```

Was I close? :)